# Overriding abstract property using more specified return type (covariance)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, overriding, abstract, covariance

```
class Base {}

abstract class A
{
    abstract public List<Base> Items { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base {}

class B : A
{ 
    private List<Derived> items;
    public override List<Derived> Items
    {
           get
           {
               return items;
           }
           set
           {
            items = value;
           }
      }
  }
```

The compiler says that B.Items must be List of Base elements "to match overridden member" A.Items. How can i make that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've tried to accomplish initially is impossible - [.NET does not support co(contra)variance for method overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837134/why-does-c-clr-not-support-method-override-co-contra-variance). The same goes for properties, because properties are just [the pair of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102639/are-c-sharp-properties-actually-methods).

But you can make your classes generic:

```
class Base {}

abstract class A<T> 
    where T : Base
{
    abstract public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base {}

class B : A<Derived>
{ 
    private List<Derived> items;
    public override List<Derived> Items
    {
           get
           {
               return items;
           }
           set
           {
            items = value;
           }
      }
  }
```

Comment: but you can use covariance for only-set or only-get properties.