# Restrictions when implementing generic interface overrides

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

If I have the following interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IPopulationUnit<T>
{
    IPopulationUnit<T> Breed();
}

 public abstract class PopulationUnit<T>:IPopulationUnit<T>
{
    public abstract PopulationUnit<T> Breed();
}
```

And then I have an implementation

```
class StringUnit : PopulationUnit<string>
{        
    public override StringUnit Breed()
    {

    }
}
```

The code doesn't compile because the `Breed` method does not match the type `IPopulationUnit<string>` but technically doesn't it? I mean, `StringUnit` itself is `PopulationUnit<string>` which itself is `IPopulationUnit<string>` so I would think it would work.

How can I restrict `StringUnit` `Breed` method to *only* return type `StringUnit` but obey the inheritance rules?

Comment: `StringUnit2: PopulationUnit<string>` meets the criteria of the method, but can't be cast to StringUnit. It makes sense that you aren't able to change the method signature like that. You might be able to do something with covariance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561023/overriding-abstract-property-using-more-specified-return-type-covariance

Comment: I';m getting an error on `public abstract PopulationUnit<T> Breed();` already because it doesn't see that as an `IPopulationUnit<T>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oekelens was close...  If you **really** wanted to do this for some strange reason, throw some constraints on it:

```
public interface IPopulationUnit<T, T1> where T1 : IPopulationUnit<T, T1>
{
    T1 Breed();
}

public abstract class PopulationUnit<T, T1> : IPopulationUnit<T, T1> where T1 : PopulationUnit<T, T1>
{
    public abstract T1 Breed();
}

public class StringUnit : PopulationUnit<string, StringUnit>
{        
    public override StringUnit Breed()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work like you had it?  Because your class **must** implement the interface as it is declared; including return type.  You can return whatever you like - but you must refer to it in the definition the same way that the interface does.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, adding a T1 to your interface and your abstract implementation:

```
    public interface IPopulationUnit<T, T1> where T1 : IPopulationUnit<T, T1>
    {
        T1 Breed();
    }

    public abstract class PopulationUnit<T> : IPopulationUnit<T, PopulationUnit<T>>
    {
        public abstract PopulationUnit<T> Breed();
    }

    class StringUnit : PopulationUnit<string>
    {
        public override PopulationUnit<string> Breed()
        {
            return new StringUnit();
        }
    }
```

I'm still getting an error if I define the override as `StringUnit Breed()` (saying it has to return `PopulationUnit<string>` in order to override `Breed()`) but you *can* actually return a `StringUnit` nonetheless from teh method itself.

Answer (score 0):

The return types in the definition must match the interface exactly.

However you are free to return anything which implements that interface:

```
public abstract class PopulationUnit<T>:IPopulationUnit<T>
{
    public abstract IPopulationUnit<T> Breed();
}

class StringUnit : PopulationUnit<string>
{        
    public override IPopulationUnit<string> Breed()
    {
        return new StringUnit(); 
    }
}
```