# CS8766: Nullability of reference types in return type doesn't match implicitly implemented member

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I've enabled Nullable References in my C# 8.0 project.  I've also set all warnings as errors to force myself to address all such warnings.  But one of them is confusing me.  It is a dependency property that returns an interface pointer that might validly be null.  Here is the property (inside a control called "LayerView")

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty ShapeBeingDrawnProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(ShapeBeingDrawn), 
    typeof(IShape), 
    typeof(LayerView),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public IShape ShapeBeingDrawn
{
    get => GetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty) as IShape;  // RIGHT SIDE OF "=>" UNDERLINED IN RED
    set => SetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty, value);
}
```

With nullable references enabled, this understandably causes a warning on the getter.  The entire right side of the get is underlined in red and I get this build error

```
1>C:\Users\jmole\Documents\Dev\Mobile\Core\Views\LayerView.xaml.cs(429,13,429,16): error CS8766:
Nullability of reference types in return type of 'IShape? LayerView.ShapeBeingDrawn.get' doesn't 
match implicitly implemented member 'IShape ILayerView.ShapeBeingDrawn.get' (possibly because of 
nullability attributes).
```

First of all,  what "implicitly" implemented member are they talking about?  This is an ***explicitly*** implemented member.  I am literally implementing it right here.  But that aside, I tried to fix this as I've fixed many other such validly nullable properties:  Make the property return a nullable reference

```
public IShape? ShapeBeingDrawn     // ONLY CHANGE IS HERE
{
    get => GetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty) as IShape; // NOW, JUST "get" IS UNDERLINED IN RED
    set => SetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty, value);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not help.  I still get the same error but this time the only part underlined in red is just the left side of the getter (the word "get").

Finally I was able to eliminate this error by changing the property back to a normal reference and using a hard cast in the getter

```
public IShape ShapeBeingDrawn
{
    get => (IShape)GetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty);
    set => SetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty, value);
}
```

But now, any code that tries to set this property to null (which is valid) gets a compiler error and I have to address that.

```
private void LayerView_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Don't do anything if we've disabled shape mouse/touch input.

    if (e.Key != Key.Escape)
        return;

    UnselectAll();
    ShapeBeingDrawn = null;  // COMPILER NO LIKEY
}
```

So what is the proper way to integrate nullable references and dependency properties?  Should I just #pragma warning disable around such problems?  I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: Does property `IShape ShapeBeingDrawn` is inherited from another `interface`? If it does, then how is it declared in that `interface`? I was able to reproduce your problem only when the property `ShapeBeingDrawn` was inherited from another `inteface`, and to fix it I had to ensure that both in inteface and in the class this property was declared `nullable` or `not nullable`. Please, check this sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cOQY4F.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it was.   Confusing error message on the surface but now that I understand it, it makes perfect sense. And if you actually went to all the trouble of trying to reproduce it, I am all the more appreciative.  Thank you.

Comment: [Explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### TL;DR

The problem occurs because property `ShapeBeingDrawn` is declared as **non-nullable** reference type `IShape` in the interface `ILayerView`, but in the class `LayerView` it is implemented as **nullable** reference type `IShape?`. Therefore compiler complains that return type of the property in the class does not match the return type in the interface.

To fix the problem we should ensure that both the interface and the class declare the property as `nullable` or `non-nullable`. If in one of them the declaration differs then we will again get compiler error.

---

### Explanation

***Why does the problem occur?***

> error CS8766: Nullability of reference types in return type of
> `'IShape? LayerView.ShapeBeingDrawn.get'` doesn't match implicitly
> implemented member `'IShape ILayerView.ShapeBeingDrawn.get'` (possibly
> because of nullability attributes).

From the error message we can see that there is an interface `ILayerView` with a `non-nullable` property `ShapeBeignDrawn`:

```
interface ILayerView
{
    IShape ShapeBeingDrawn { get; set; }
}
```

and a class `LayerView` that implements this interface but declares property `ShapeBeignDrawn` as `nullable`:

```
public class LayerView
{
    public IShape? ShapeBeingDrawn
    {
        get => GetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty) as IShape;
        set => SetValue(ShapeBeingDrawnProperty, value);
    }
}
```

So the interface declares property as `non-nullable` but the class implements it as `nullable`. Therefore compiler complains that return type of the `getter` of the property in the class does not match the return type in the interface.

***Question:***

> First of all, what "implicitly" implemented member are they talking
> about?

***Answer:***

When we declare a property compiler implicitly generates for it [two methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102679/12833205): `get_PropertyName` and `set_PropertyName`. Therefore compiler complains for the return type of the implicitly implemented `getter` method.

---

***How should we fix the problem?***

To fix the problem we should ensure that both an interface and a class declare a property as `nullable` or `non-nullable`. If in one of them the declaration differs then we will again get compiler error `CS8766`.

Here is a [code sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qG4mOr) that reproduces the problem and gives a hint how to fix it.